# Parallelisation over the cloud

Tags: parallel-processing, cloud

I have a routine named isIn(i), where i is an integer, which returns a number between 0 and 1.
My main routine is a for loop calling every isIn to find the best match.
Suppose now that I put this algorithm on a cloud service (e.g. OVH or Amazon).
What is the best programming language I should use? (given that it has to be well-known, I was thinking of Python). 
What is the best way to efficiently parallelise this algorithm? (OS used? Communication protocol?).

Subsidiary question: how do I scale it efficiently? (for example if the main routine is called by many users)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking what you might consider is setting up an image that simply presents an RPC service.  Python can do this fairly easily.  You could have the image just boot and launch a python application that spins up a simple http server and listens for JSON queries.

It can parse those queries... perform isln(x) and return a result in json.

Then you can setup an http load balancer with a public interface to route requests dynamically across however many instances of the rpc service you deploy.  You may consider ways to dynamically grow your load balancers as well as your number of rpc instances.

This would be in line with how most cloud applications currently operate.

Comment: That's some very good advice Matt, do you have a link explaining this into further detail?